# How to get an xsp value from URL link using Java

Tags: java, javascript, xpages

I am trying to retrieve the page name(.xsp)from the URL of the current page using Java. i have been able to accomplish the same thing with the Javascript below

```
context.getUrl().getSiteRelativeAddress(context).toString()
```

and it works but i want to get the same thing don using Java.

Comment: Try exploring the HttpServletRequest class (or equals class that XPages has 
e.g. 
var request:com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletRequest = con.getRequest();

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? You talk about a URL and then use context.getUrl() which gets the URL of the current page. But you can just use view.getPageName() to get the xsp name of the current XPage

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten yes i want to get the URL of the current page with Java

Comment: The URL of the current page (including protocol, domain name and port?) and not the page name? Then please update your question title and question content to reflect this

Comment: i want to get the pagename from the current URl i think i need to get the URL first before i could get the page name

Comment: Just use view.getPageName() to get the xsp name of the current XPage

Comment: which Java class do i need to import am getting view cannot be resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get SSJS variable names via Java is `resolveVariable`. This should work:

```
XSPContext context = (XSPContext) ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "context");
String pageName = context.getUrl().getSiteRelativeAddress(context).toString();
```

(Updated with correct syntax for second line, thanks Knut)

Comment: am getting the error getSiteRelativeAddress(() is undefined

Comment: Second line should be `String pageName = context.getUrl().getSiteRelativeAddress(context).toString();`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the snippet, just in case anyone else tries it without looking at the comments (something I know I might do myself!)